# Localization to a different alphabet

Tags: .net

So, I have a finished application written in C# with full support for localization. So far we have done translations to different languages but they were all using Latin alphabet. Now, I need to translate my app to Russian Cyrillic.

Can someone give me quick rundown on what needs to be done to do this conversion?

Comment: Strings are UTF-8 encoded in .NET, so they support cyrillic characters. The question is a little bit unspecific. No information on **how** you realized localization. Without some more backround or a specific problem you are facing it is hard to give you an answer!

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I have done three things to ensure complete localization: 1 - Forms are localized using Localization=true and rewriting labels and such in another language. 2 - All strings inside the application are stored in resx files. One file for each language or dialect. 3 - All translatable strings in my database are stored in separate tables.

Comment: @Aschratt In memory strings are UTF-16 encoded in .net. How strings are serialized depends on context. But of course your main point remains valid: Most of .net supports Unicode and thus cyrillic characters.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Sorry for the mix-up... However it doesn't actually matter if it's UTF-8 or UTF-16, both support cyrillic characters.

Comment: It's my fault that the question is misinterpreted. I'm asking how can I do this. Like, should I invest in a keyboard with an Cyrillic layout and then retype all the labels or there is a way in VS designer to just change the font and the letters will convert automatically?